# How can I pass text into a directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<markdown>{{ q.qv.text }}</markdown>
<markdown>{{ q.qs.text }}</markdown>
```

and a directive:

```
app.directive('markdown', function () {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(element.text());
            element.html(htmlText);
        }
    }
});
```

It doesn't work at all. What I would like to do is to pass in the contents of $scope.q.qv.text or whatever scope variable I might choose.  How can I modify the directive or change the way it's called so that it takes a scope variable value ?

Comment: Try <markdown>#hello markdown!</markdown>

Comment: I can't do that as I have the data in the $scope.q.qv.text variable

Comment: You don't use isolate scope so `scope` in directive has the same id of your controller. Therefore just write: `var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(scope.q.qs.text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass values from directive view to its controller as:

```
<markdown abc=val>... </markdown>  // abc="123" or try with abc="{{ q.qv.text }}" for your case
```

Now in your controller:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs.abc);
    }
```

Comment: So in the above example I could use abc=q.qv.text ? Would I need to put the q.qv.text in "" or put $scope first ? Can you give your answer as an example using my code above and show how it's called so other can see also.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try with that.. The crux is provide a rendered value as attribute to directive and it can be accessed through 'attrs'